# Making java packages

Tags: java, classpath

My Java classes organization has gotten a little messy so I'm going over something I've skipped in my Java learning: the classpath. I can't quiet get beloved classes to compile in the packages I have created for them. Here's my folder hierarchy:

```
.
com/
    david/
        Greet.java

        greeter/
            SayHello.java
            SayGoodbye.java
```

Where SayHello's constructor just prints "hello" and SayGoodbye's prints "Goodbye" and Greet's main method just creates those two objects. At the top of SayHello is package com.david.greeter; and likewise with SayGoodbye and Greet's is package com.david;

In the greeter folder I was able to compile both java files but if I go to the current directory (the directory that holds com) and do javac -cp "com.david.greeter.*" com/david/Greet.java it says it can't find the classes as well as saying package com.david.greeter doesn't exist. I've also tried setting the $CLASSPATH manually.

I'm at my wit's end here, Stackoverflow (as I normally am when I post here). Do any of you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The java compiler will traverse the sub-directories of the classpath looking for the packages it needs.

So, your command line should be as follows:

```
javac -cp "." com/david/Greet.java
```

When the compiler sees a reference to com.david.greeter.SayHello while compiling Greet.java it will start with the directory in the classpath and traverse the hierarchy looking for the package it needs.

Answer (score 1):

First, as documented in [Setting the Classpath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html), the way you're currently setting your class path is wrong. Class path entries should be filename or directory. So using `com.david.greeter.*` doesn't make any sense. Second, the current directory is in the class path by default:

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

So if you execute `javac` (here is the [man page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) by the way) from the folder containing `com`, you don't have to tweak anything, just type:

```
javac com/david/Greet.java
```

And `javac` will go through the directory tree to find references (e.g. `SayHello` if you're using it from `Greet`) and compile them too.

And by the way, if you have to set the class path, don't use the `$CLASSPATH` environment variable, this is just a bad practice in most case, prefer the `-cp` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the folder containing com, then try this:

```
javac -cp . com\david\Greet.java
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect (as the compiler has already told you):

> javac -cp "com.david.greeter.*

Open a command shell and navigate to the directory that contains the "com" directory.

I think you really want this to compile SayHello.java and SayGoodbye.java:

> javac -cp . com/david/greeter/*.java

This to compile Greet.java:

> javac -cp . com/david/*.java

And this to run:

> java -cp . com.david.Greet

Answer (score 0):

The "com" directory should not be current, it should be a child directory to current. You need step one level upper and launch again. No extra care about classpath should be needed at this point.