# Include an interface from the same package (Java)

Tags: java, interface, package, javac

I'm new to Java (C++ guy myself) and am trying to compile a simple program (testing different random number algorithms) in Java.  I have an interface that I want to use to implement another class with, both of these items are in the same package.

So I have two files right now in my "Random" package directory--"RandomInterface.java" and "RandomTest1.java" (which implements RandomInterface).  I can use javac to compile RandomInterface.java just fine, but I get the following error when I then try to compile RandomTest1:

```
RandomTest1.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol: class RandomInterface
public class RandomTest1 implements RandomInterface
                                 ^
1 error
```

I declare both files to be part of the same package (Random) as the first line of each file.  What do I need to do to include the RandomInterface class into the compile command for RandomTest1?

Thanks!

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249066/making-java-packages/2249096#2249096

Comment: I've tried adding -cp "." to the command-line arguments for javac, didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your text says `RandomInterface` but your code says `RandomClass`. Is this just a simple oversight, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd originally started with the interface as an abstract class instead--I guess I'd copied the error message from before I'd switched the it to an interface.  I'll update my post with the proper current error message--still the same thing though.

Answer (score 0):

In java we use `extends` keyword for extending class and `implements` for interface and where as you are using wrong keyword for wrong type. If this is class then you should `extends` it.